# Missing Partition Space After Installation

Tags: partitioning

After I installed Ubuntu 11.04 in a partition that I delegated 100GB for. I realize that I only have 10GB left, where did the rest of the space go?

The volume size states I have 100GB for that partition.

Screenshot (DF Command):

[image]

Comment: please, add output of command df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have installed ubuntu trought wubi, on some windows partition that you had 100GB spare space left, didnt changed size of installation. **If so, you can store files to your windows partitions as well**, looks like you have one in /media/B6E... and you can access partition that wubi was installed on trough /host .

If it is not true, add output of command

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd[abc]
```

//edit

this command will print partition sizes of your disks sda sdb sdc, but not needed.

As mentioned here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=777797 , wubi is not intended to be long time solution, i wouldn't  recommended wubi for storing lot of data there because of speed ( it is slower than regular install ).

Navigate to folder /host, you can see that you have rest of that 100gb available there...

Comment: Yes I did install it through wubi from Windows platform, and yes I would like to use all that space that I delegated 100GB to from /sdc2.

Would running the sudo command above achieve that? 

TIA!

Comment: I did not know this, shall I do a fresh install of Ubuntu then? :)